# Javascript call function with “this” on event

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to call function with "this" from event?
If remove "this", it will work.

```js
function Parent()
{
 this.child = function()
 {
  alert("called child");
 };
    $("#btn1").click
 (
  function() 
  {
   this.child(); // doesn't work
  }
 );
}
var objp = new Parent();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="submit" id="btn1">Submit</button>
```

Comment: don't bind event inside function.put `$("#btn1").click` outside function.

Comment: `this` inside the event handler is the Element on which the event occured.

Comment: What you are really trying to do?